# how can i change/modify the height of status bar in android. can we do by reflection or can we modify the dimen.xml file in android

Tags: android

I want to change status bar height of android device using an application for non rooted devices.
I found a way to modify it using xPosed installer but it is for rooted device.
I also tried to get the height of status bar at run time using java reflection technique and is able to set the new height but the new height is not reflected to status bar UI.

Below is the code snippet which I tried:

```
      field = c.getDeclaredField("status_bar_height");
      field.setAccessible(true);
      field.setInt("status_bar_height", 2000 & ~Modifier.FINAL);
```

Do I need to modify the dimens.xml file as well or this value of status_bar_height can be reflected directly. 
Please let me know any changes which I have to make.

Thanks in advance

Comment: if you REALLY want to do it, well after you update the height, make sure you get the status bar View and call invalidate() on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from this way, i'm trying to set it but its not effected on UI. at last when i'm getting the status bar height then its give default height.

private void getApplicationStatusBar(){

```
    Class<?> c = null;
    Object object = null;
    Field field = null;
    try {
        Log.v("TESTING_STATUS_BAR", "Before starting process");
        try {
            c = Class.forName("com.android.internal.R$dimen");
            Log.v("C", "C bar: " + c);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.v("TESTING_STATUS_BAR", "After getting class");

        try {
            object = c.newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        Field[] declaredFields = object.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        try {
            field = c.getDeclaredField("status_bar_height");
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.v("TESTING_STATUS_BAR", "After getting status_bar_height_field");
        field.setAccessible(true);

        try {
            field.setInt("status_bar_height", 80);
            Log.v("field.getInt(\"status_bar_height\")", "Test: " + field.getInt("status_bar_height"));
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.v("TESTING_STATUS_BAR", "After setting field");

        int result = 0;
        int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
        if (resourceId > 0) {
            result = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
        }
        Log.v("TESTING_STATUS_BAR", "Status bar: " + result);

    }catch(Exception e){

    }
```